# update gives too many rows errors,please guide

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from tbl_a;
SRNO    T_TEXT
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        a
2        b
3        a
3        b
4        a
----

select * from tbl_b;
SRNO    T_TEXT
1   
1   
1   
2   
2   
3   
3   
4
```

i want to update `tbl_b.t_text` with values from `tbl_a.t_text`.
i do that it gives returned too many rows. I can do this trough a for loop,
but want it through update statement only.

Here is the SQL I've tried@

```
update tbl_b b 
set b.t_text = (select a.t_text from tbl_a a 
                 where a.srno = b.srno and b.t_text is null) 
where exists ( select 1 from tbl_a c 
                where c.srno = b.srno);
```

It throws error `single row subquery return more than one row`.

Comment: Can you copy the exact query and error into the question?

Comment: You cannot really do what you want.  Your tables have no unique link between them.  You probably want to use row number, but SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of row number, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Do you just want a copy of tbl_b? If so then truncate the tbl_b and do an insert tbl_b select * from tbl_a

Comment: thanks,we can use srno as the joining key tbl_a.srno=tbl_b.srno,it can be done through anon block.so there is no update statement solution for it ?

Comment: Just recreate the table with CREATE ..AS SELECT if the SRNO columns are the same.An update will run into cross join issues.Question is why would you need 2 identical tables

Comment: Actually the main tables contains many columns i just gave an example of what needs to be done, so CTAS is not an option.

Comment: In table 'tbl_a' there are multiple values for id 1, i.e. a,b,c. Hence for id 1 in table 'tbl_b', update query is returning multiple values, instead of single value.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the UPDATE statement you tried to execute, along with the exact error message which is being generated. Thanks.

Comment: update tbl_b b set b.t_text = (select a.t_text from tbl_a a where a.srno = b.srno and b.t_text is null)
where exists ( select 1 from tbl_a c where c.srno = b.srno); error "single row subquery return more than one row". thanks

Comment: i will accept  Gordon Linoff resolution as the query i gave is not possible by standalone update in absence of any primary key.thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to update tbl_b

```
begin
    for i in (select a.* from tbl_a a) loop
        update tbl_b b
        set b.t_text=i.t_text
        where b.srno=i.srno
        and b.t_text is null
        and rownum=1;
    end loop;
end;
```

I wish it helps you.

Comment: thanks , but i had this code with me ,i wanted a standalone update which i think is not possible.

Comment: Yes. I think it's not possible, too.

Answer (score -1):

you can  use Below query

```
UPDATE tbl_a
SET tbl_a.T_TEXT=(SELECT tbl_b.T_TEXT
FROM tbl_b
WHERE tbl_b.SRNO=tbl_a.SRNO);
```

Comment: This will throw the same error the OP complains of.

Comment: the answer given(by prashant) is wrong,it gives the same error.

Comment: you cann't use update for this table with this design because you don't have unique column in 2 tables.
@Gordon-Linoff said that.